# Parsing string literals from a file in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am reading a string from a file in ruby. This string has escape sequences in them that I would like turned into the appropriate characters.

For example I might have a string like this:

```
"this is a string\n"
```

With the actual characters `\` and `n` in the file, not the newline character.

Is there a built in function to decode these literals? Or will I have to write something to do it manually?

Note that I'm not using rails, and the file data is not json.

Comment: What are the escape sequences ? Ruby-like ? C-like ? JSON ? Depending on the list of allowed escape sequences, there might be existing solutions.

Comment: I am happy with whatever the ruby standard list of escaped characters is. I thought there might have been a pair of standard escape/unescape functions for these characters, but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: The real question is where does this file come from? The appropriate way to decode escape sequences depends on how they were encoded in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you are satisfied with the escape sequences supported by the JSON format, you can do something like this:

```
require 'json'

def unescape(str)
  JSON.parse("[\"#{str}\"]")[0]
end

p unescape("\\nline\\u0040")          # "\nline@"
```

Please note that the ruby JSON parser does not accept naked values, so the string needs to be wrapped in an array or an object.

The JSON parser will also raise errors if the string cannot be correctly parsed so you should add some error handling code.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a plain text file (e.g. not JSON, YAML, or another data format that has specific escape sequences) then those character sequences have no special meaning. Therefore, if you want to give them one in the context of your application you'll have to write the code to do that yourself. For newlines specifically, you could do something like this:

```
input.gsub!('\n', "\n")
```

Comment: This is what is was hoping to avoid, but it seems like it might be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%q{}` 
    %q{"this is a string\n"}
    => "\"this is a string\n\""

This way it will escape the string characters.

From the [documentation](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-perl/):

> There’s a general delimited string and regex quoting syntax similar to
>   Perl’s. It looks like %q{this} (single-quoted), or %Q{this}
>   (double-quoted), and %w{this for a single-quoted list of words}. You
>   %Q|can| %Q(use) %Q^other^ delimiters if you like.

**EDIT:**
Since I misunderstand the question, I think your best option, if you do not want to rely on third-party libs (like JSON), is to replace with proper values:

> str.gsub(/(\n)+/,"\n")

Comment: I think OP wants to decode the string literal, not produce it.

Comment: The code you gave doesn't do what the OP described. All that will do is replace groups of multiple newline characters with a single newline. E.g. `"asdf/n/nasdf"` will become `"asdf/nasdf"`, but `"\\n"` will not become `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope there's a better option, but it's good to know that you can achieve this with [`Kernel#eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-eval):

```
literal_from_file = '"this is a string\n"'

puts literal_from_file       # print the literal first
puts eval(literal_from_file) # and then print the interpreted string
```

will print:

```
"this is a string\n"
this is a string
```

Comment: As mentioned in OP's first sentence, they are reading a string from a file. You should never eval something that you don't trust 100%. Honestly you should probably never use eval at all unless you have a very good reason for it.

Comment: @Jazzepi I'm aware of that. However, in case OP was looking for a quick solution to parse a file that he controls, this could be a good enough option.